# donde poner la logica del negocio en Django

Tags: django, lógica

Un amigo me recomendó que leyera el libro two scoop of Django y quedé maravillado con las recomendaciones que hace para hacer un proyecto de Django robusto y bien diseñado. Esta lectura me creó una duda y es donde pongo la lógica del negocio, pongo un ejemplo. Supongamos que tengo dos modelos:

> models.py

```
class Chispas(models.Model):
    sabor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Helado(models.Model):
    sabor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tiene_cono = models.BooleanField()
    cantidad_chispas = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Supongamos que cada vez que agrego un helado, si lleva chispas tengo que restarlo del modelo `Chispas` y comprobar que halla una cantidad disponible. En el libro recomiendan poner esta lógica en `models.py` o en `forms.py`. Dónde y cómo debería poner esto?  Si crear un modelo requiere modificar los datos de otro modelo, ¿dónde debo hacerlo?

Comment: En cualquiera es valido, pero si vas a comprobar la cantidad disponible de chispas varias veces alrededor de tu proyecto te recomiendo hacerlo en un método de tu modelo (`models.py`) de esta manera evitamos repetir código y saber la disponibilidad de las chispas en cualquier momento.

Comment: @JulioCesar  Si crear un modelo requiere modificar los datos de otro modelo, ¿dónde debo hacerlo? Esa es mi pregunta. Sería modificar el save() de ese modelo o hacerlo de otra forma?

Comment: Para tu caso en concreto recomiendo utilizar señales, específicamente la señal `post_save`, en la señal restas las chispas que utilizo el helado y listo.

Comment: Si modificas los campos del propio modelo y esas modificaciones no son muy complejas puedes sobrescribir el metodo `save()`, por ejemplo establecer el slug de titulo.

Answer (score 0):

Hay una [charla](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yG3ZdxBb1oo) muy interesante sobre este tema, proponen colocar toda la lógica del negocio en los modelos y los que no se puedan colocarlos en 2 archivos más(selectores y servicios); en si hay mucho más cosas y reglas.
La guía de estilo completa esta [acá](https://github.com/HackSoftware/Django-Styleguide).

Aunque también hay [críticas](https://www.b-list.org/weblog/2020/mar/16/no-service/) en contra de esta guía de estilo, por ejemplo, la de uno de los release managers de django. Él dice que la lógica del negocio debería colocarse en los modelos, managers o querysets.

Answer (score 0):

Si bien la idea de colocar la mayoría de la lógica del negocio junto al módelo resulta favorable, en la mayoría de los casos esta idea no termina de ser clara en especial cuando vas comenzando. En resumen yo mencionaría 4 componentes principales:

1. **Managers.** Encapsulan la lógica a nivel de tablas o modelos completos.
2. **Propertys o métodos de instancia.** Encapsulan la lógica a nivel de rows o registros de una tabla.
3. **Métodos especiales.** Métodos tales como save, o delete definidos por Django, esencialmente la única lógica que se agregaría aquí sería aquella que se dispara cuando ocurre un cambio en un registro tal como una actualización. Aunque he visto que algunas personas aconsejan agregar la lógica aquí frente a usar señales, la misma documentación remarca algunas cosas a considerar.

> Note that the delete() method for an object is not necessarily called
> when deleting objects in bulk using a QuerySet or as a result of a
> cascading delete. To ensure customized delete logic gets executed, you
> can use pre_delete and/or post_delete signals.
>
> Unfortunately, there isn’t a workaround when creating or updating
> objects in bulk, since none of save(), pre_save, and post_save are
> called.

[Nota Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)

4. **Señales.** Te permite agregar acciones que se disparan ante eventos o cambios en una instancia de un modelo y ademas te permiten agregar acciones a modelos que vienen en librerías de terceros que agregas a tu proyecto.

Antes de finalizar, solo mencionar que la razón por la que unos prefieren los métodos especiales frente a las señales es por que es más fácil ir al modelo y ver toda la lógica plasmada en su método save frente a tener que ir a buscar las señales que afectan a un model que por buena práctica deberían estar en el archivo `signals.py` de la app.